# Is it possible to hook up Devise Registration Controller with Administrate dashboard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am creating a rails employee dashboard app where I am able to view a list of employees. For this application, I am the only user that should be able to view the administrative dashboard page. I've implemented my admin functionality by using the nifty [administrate](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate) gem. An example app that showcases the dashboard can be found by viewing clicking this url [Administrate example](https://administrate-prototype.herokuapp.com/admin). My dashboard is identical and is nothing special. However, I will run into the occasion where I need to create other users/amins (Human Resources) to log in and to be able to edit, remove employee listings.

For authentication, I am using the awesome [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem and am successfully able to login, signup, signout, etc. Here is the catch though. I need to be able to create new users through the administrate dashboard. I have the dashboard set up to display the user fields but I am currently unable to create a user. Here is a picture of my user dashboard for reference

[image]

The problem I am facing is that when I enter a password for `Encrypted password` I am unable to do so because of the `Password can't be blank` validation.

Viewing my logs, I am able to see that when I go to devise's signup page, it goes to a `Devise::RegistrationsController` while creation of my User with the administrate gem goes through `Admin::UsersController`. Surely, someone in the community has used a combination of creating users through an admin dashboard with devise. Does anyone have any recommendations of how to customize this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a problem with strong params. You have to sanitize those parameters. Cleanest solution, at least for me, is to override the RegistrationsController like so:

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation) # list every parameter you'd like to register with
  end
end
```

and map this controller in *routes.rb* like so:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

You can get inspired in this [article](http://jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html).

Also I've noticed that you are trying to manipulate with encrypted_password field. That's not a good idea. Devise will handle that for you. You can render the input for password instead (that might as well be the issue all along).

Answer (score 0):

The parameters seems to be the issue. You are trying to set protected parameters. Try sending only the following parameters.

`[:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :mobile ]`

Make sure you have permitted above parameters in `Admin::UsersController`

After adding the user you have to confirm the user, if you have `:confirmable` in your user model. You can do so in  `Admin::UsersController` after creation of `user` object.

`user.confirm`